# Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: classes.dex

Tags: android, eclipse, executable-jar

I am trying to add a customized dialog box. For that I included a .jar file             `"annotations-6341fdfc066d3c9db92480c623dc4535"`. But when I am trying to run program it gives error like below

```
[2013-07-03 14:55:02 - TanetApp] Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: classes.dex
Origin 1: C:\Users\Rupesh\NewWrkplace\TanetApp\bin\classes.dex
Origin 2: C:\Users\Rupesh\NewWrkplace\TanetApp\libs\annotations-6341fdfc066d3c9db92480c623dc4535.jar
```

I also googled it but I am getting confused.
This might be a possibility

1. Classes.dex is also present in that annotations.jar file,but how to exclude classes.dex from .jar file ?